# Capture IE Close event using C# windows

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer

I need to capture the IE close event whenever user close the IE.

I have to show the windows pop-up parallel as the alert message(Your session get closed) using windows application(C#).

Please share how I can capture the  close IE event.

Comment: Will you install that windows application on every client machine, that is accessing your web application via IE ?

Comment: Yes, the windows application is installed on every client machine.

Comment: Does your application also launch the IE instance?